# Making jquery Switch statement with checking attribute value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have popup menu with links. When selected one of the items, selected class should be added with background. I tried to do it with switch statement in jquery. Every menu link has different attribute value.
How can i select value of them with case?

```
$(".franchise-item__img,.fr-banner").click(function(){
    switch ($(this).attr('select-data')){
        case 'banner':
        {
            $('.fr-product').removeClass('selected');
            $('.fr-banner').addClass('selected');
            break;
        }
        case 'product':
        {   
            $(".fr-banner").removeClass('selected');
            $('.fr-product').addClass('selected');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks i got it!

```
$(".item-banner a").click(function(event){
    $('.list-wrap li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');   
    event.preventDefault();   
});
```

But now i have question, if i can't use switch, how can i have 12 different modal window content?

Comment: FYI, you know that this switch statement is just JavaScript? It's not jQuery, you just happen to use it in an event handler that you assign using jQuery.

Comment: If you have only two products,why can't you use toggleClass in jquery ?

Comment: I have 12 products, it's just example

Comment: Why do they all have different classes? If each of them would have a shared class (as well), like `menu-item`, you could just deselect all `menu-item`s, except the event target. You can write one generic piece of code, that is completely independent of the number of items you have or their specific names/texts/descriptions/classes.

Comment: Thanks, it helped!